# Service/Port based DNS redirection? or variant

Tags: domain-name-system

resolving a domain to a different IP based on port/service

ex, mineplex.com redirects to one IP always when using a web client. But will redirect you to another IP when using a minecraft client.

Although the nslookup for mineplex.com using google's dns results in 199.83.134.131.
When I wireshark my minecraft client it results in packets going to another ip.

Any possible explaination?

Comment: Most like the client simply requests a different DNS record. Wire shark should allow you to see that as well...

Answer (score 1):

For client software that knows to look up [`SRV` records](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2782) it is certainly possible to do this.

An `SRV` has the following format:

```
_Service._Proto.Name TTL Class SRV Priority Weight Port Target
```

eg:

```
_minecraft._tcp.example.com. 86400 IN SRV 0 5 25565 foo.example.com.
```

So when such a client is told to connect to `example.com` it will look up `_minecraft._tcp.example.com IN SRV` and receive this record which among other things includes the port and actual target name (expected to have `A`/`AAAA` records).

Unfortunately when it comes to some of the major, older, protocols like for instance HTTP the client base is generally unaware of `SRV`.

Comment: SRV records are a fantastic solution, its a shame the uptake is so extremely limited in the real world. :-(